# how to know the depth of a git's shallow clone?

Tags: git, git-clone

If I retrieve a shallow clone, e.g.

```
git clone --depth 10 http://foo.bar/baz.git
```

Does `git` have any command to retrieve the depth of this clone? (e.g. a command that simply prints `10`).

Comment: I had a really simple case where `git log <branch> | wc -l` worked for me

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: no.  The number is not stored anywhere (unless you store it yourself—and it might be nice if Git saved it in `.git/config` somewhere).

A repository is shallow (by Git's internal definition) if and only if the file `.git/shallow` exists.  The *contents* of this file are a bit sneaky: most of Git treats it in exactly the same way as `.git/grafts`.  That is, each line in the `shallow` file contains a commit hash ID (and nothing else, vs `grafts`, where each line is followed by all the grafted parent IDs: since the line is empty, there are no parent IDs and the commit becomes a root commit).  (Git can flag it internally as "not really a root", indicating that it has parents that simply have never been obtained.  To be completely reliable, this would also require ensuring that no *actual* root commit IDs are ever stored in the file, and I am not sure if that is the case.)

You could compute a max depth of all references: starting with each reference, count graph depth from that tipmost commit down to a (possibly grafted) root.  This would not, however, necessarily be the number passed to `--depth` (here or, later, with a `--depth` given to `git fetch`).

Suppose, for instance, that we clone a repository that has only two commits, while also using `--depth 10`.  The deepest chain is either one or two commits long, since there are only two commits: one (real) root for certain, and one commit that might have the other as its parent, or might be another (real) root commit.  If—this is the case I do not know the answer to—the `.git/shallow` file never contains real roots, it would be empty at this point and we would know that however long the longest chain is, the `--depth` argument must have been greater than that, but we would not know the actual number.

Suppose, on the other hand, we clone a 10-or-more-commit repository, with our `--depth 10`, and get a chain of 10 commits terminated by a fake-root-graft.  Then we add two *new* commits to this 10-long chain, so that we have a 12-commit chain.  The `--depth` is still 10, but counting chains, we find 12.

So, this shows two ways that a computed count could be too small or too large.  In many circumstances, though, the computed count would work well.  To get computed counts, use `git for-each-ref` to find each reference, and `git rev-list --count --first-parent` on each found reference.  Whatever maximum you get is likely the depth number, or something close enough.