# What information is kept in the `.git/shallow` file?

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline, shallow-clone

I know git considers a repository shallow if it has a `.git/shallow` file in the `.git` directory.

When `cat`-ing the file on a locally cloned shallow repository of depth 5 I see only one hash while when I run a jenkins job to clone the same repo at depth 5 I see multiple hashes.

**What information is kept in this file? How is it determined?**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37203240/1030675

Comment: Note that `--depth <n>` implies `--single-branch`, which explains the single hash. Perhaps the Jenkins job is using `--no-single-branch` to override that.